# How do I get a Tkinter scrollbar to correctly scroll a windowed frame of buttons so all buttons are visable/ click?able

Tags: python, tkinter, window, tkinter-canvas

I'm having an issue correctly viewing a large (643) frame of buttons,
I have had other issues like.

1. Learning make the buttons scroll-able,
   Which I fixed by learning to use the `canvas.create_window` to do so.
2. The contents of said `canvas` window spilling off the sides off of the sides
   the buttons spilling off the side of the canvas
   Which i fixed by containing the `canvas` in a top level frame instead of the root window.

But now that I'm at an impasse with the view and use abilities of everything, I do not want to resort to a list of `ttk notebook` tabs, as that seems crude.

The issue seems to be a sub-sector of problem 2, as the buttons are being rendered based on the size of my screen, and that in itself just seems to bother some.

a smaller addition of this issue seems to be that the scroll bar leaves a load of space leaving tons of room to be used, ill post an answer to my own question if i find it. Normally I dont ask questions but leaving a bread trail for future devolpers is nice,

Screen shot below [image: Tkinter window w/canvas and vsb]

```py
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import BOTH, BOTTOM, LEFT, RIGHT, TOP, X, Y, Button, Canvas, Frame, Tk
import matplotlib
import tkinter.ttk as ttk 
import sys
# caution: path[0] is reserved for script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, "/home/will/Projects/CoinBaseADVtrade_Data")

import Data

class GUI(Tk):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.top_frame = Frame(self)
        self.top_frame.pack(side=TOP, )
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.top_frame, bg="Black",width=177)
        self.frame = Frame(self.top_frame,height=20,width=400)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self.top_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        self.canvas.pack(side=TOP,)
        self.canvas.create_window((0,0),window=self.frame,anchor="n")

        self.frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=self.canvas: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))
        self.populate(self.frame)

    def populate(self,frame):
        products = Data.Products().list_products()
        for i in range(len(products)):
            print(products.iloc[i].name)
            Button(frame,height =5,width = 20,text=products.iloc[i].name).pack(side=TOP, padx=5,pady=3)
        pass



GUI().mainloop()
```

I've tried things like Y view Containing the canvas better
and neither solution yielded any results and proved to messy my code

Comment: Note that there is limitation on the maximum width and height of a frame.  Also it is not a good design to have so many widgets created simultaneously.

Comment: Using buttons to access a large amount of information is not the best option. I suggest using a Listbox with scrollbar. It can easily handle large data and avoids the buttons in frame in canvas palaver.

Comment: I agree with @Derek - at the risk of not answering the question at hand, I think you'd be better served to look for a different approach. A scrollable list of hundreds of buttons is bad UX; this use case is exactly what a `Listbox` is for (though this *is* still a lot to scroll through). And as a bonus, you won't need to worry about using a `canvas` to get things to scroll correctly - just put the `Listbox` in a containing `Frame` and bind a scrollbar similarly to what you've already shown here.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Just wanted to poke around and see if I can do bad design in a good way lmao, Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous comments reccomending listview, while a good upgrade to a bad code, im resorting to TTK.treeview instead. As I believe A jump to minimal to complex deserves the full jump and it will be better in every way to list view for my purposes,

others may find list view more beneficial than I.